# Simple plot but the origin is not clear

Tags: plotting, functions

I am having problem with the simple plot below.
    Plot[1/(1-x), {x, 0, 1}]

I got the result:
As you can see the origin (0,0) is not clear. The value of the function at x = 0 is one but it is not show clearly in the plot. 
Could you suggest some ways so that I can see the origin and the value of the function at x = 0 clearly?
[image]

I would like to have it something like this:
[image]

**P.S:**
With the help of J.M, I have the desired plot now. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Look up `PlotRange`.

Comment: Well, thank you very much! I got the result now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is pleasant in Mma, is that one can achieve the same goal by several ways. Try also this:

```
Plot[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

giving:

[image]

or even this:

```
 Plot[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},Ticks -> {Automatic, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I usually use the `AxesOrigin` method because you don't have to think about the plot range, +1

Comment: Well, very impressive! Thanks a lot!